# How should I use the alternate formula of the derivative to “mathematically” show that the derivative of $f(x)=|x-2|$ at $x=2$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

The title is the question. But I’m not sure how one can “mathematically” show the derivative? Can someone please interpret that part of the problem? Thanks!!

Comment: Which alternate formula for the derivative? There are a very large number of them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the alternate definition of the derivative is

$$f'(c)=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

Note that this definition requires a limit.  Thus we must have that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{\color{red}{-}}}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\rightarrow c^{\color{red}{+}}}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

Take left and right limits using the definition here.  What happens?

Comment: They must be equal to each other in order for the limit to exist?

Comment: Yup!  So what happens when you substitute $f(x)=|x-2|$?

Comment: Note too that geometrically, the tangent line at $x=2$ is not unique....  Another way to help the intuition of why the derivative doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should draw the graph of the one variable function. Then take the right and left limit at the "corner" point of that graph, which gives you different values. In your function $f$, it happens at $x=2$.